# Having trouble clicking on a button/link with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I'm having real trouble clicking on this "button" link in this web app. It's defined as so:

```
<tr>
<td id="mainleftlinkzoneover" width="9" valign="top">
<td id="mainleftlinkzoneover" class="mainleftlinks" width="151" title="Online Training">  Online Training</td>
</tr>
```

Notice how there is no name or ID to use. Thanks! I've tried clicking it by Link Text. Nope. I've tried clicking it by partial link text. Nope.

Not sure why that isn't working but I've only been doing Selenium for a whole day. I'm successfully logging into the application so things are working. If I use By.PartialLinkText it doesn't fail but it doesn't click the link either.

```
 WebElement OnlineTrainBtn = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Training"));
 OnlineTrainBtn.click();
```

I think I may be left with either Xpath or CssSelector but I have no idea how to write the search string.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, I have ten or twelve more "buttons" like this to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

The `By.PartialLinkText` searches among the `<a>` tags.

So in your case, I would use an CSS selector to match the title:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[title='Online Training']")).click();
```

You could also use an XPath to partially match the text:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(., 'Training')]")).click();
```

Comment: That worked VERY well thank you SO much. Now I understand the format too. This will help me with verifications as well. Love this place!